# How to obtain inner tags value in XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

```
XDocument coordinates = XDocument.Load("http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch");
System.IO.StreamWriter StreamWriter1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(DestFile);
XNamespace nsContent = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/";
string pchild = null;

foreach (var item in coordinates.Descendants("item"))
{
   string link = item.Element("guid").Value;

   //string content = item.Element(nsContent + "encoded").Value;
   foreach (var child in item.Descendants(nsContent + "encoded"))
   {
      pchild = pchild + child.Element("p").Value;
   }

   StreamWriter1.WriteLine(link + Environment.NewLine +  Environment.NewLine + pchild + Environment.NewLine);
}

StreamWriter1.Close();
```

If i use Commented line code *(`string content = item.Element(nsContent + "encoded").Value;`)* instead of inner `for loop` than it will fetch the value of `<conten:encoded>` element but it contains all links, images etc etc. And I want only text.

For that I have tried to use this filter (inner for loop) but its showing error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please suggest me code so that I can store only text and remove all other links, `<img>` tags etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of `item.Element(nsContent + "encoded").Value` is **html** not **xml**. You should parse it accordingly, such as using  [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

See the example below

```
string content = item.Element(nsContent + "encoded").Value;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(new StringReader(content));
var text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine,
                doc.DocumentNode
                .Descendants("p")
                .Select(n => "\t" + System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(n.InnerText))
            );
```

Comment: Sorry, `Join` was an my own extension method. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would start by using a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Then, I suspect that sometimes, the "child" doesn't have a "p" element, so you can check before using it:

```
foreach (var child in item.Descendants(nsContent + "encoded"))
{
  if (child.Element("p") != null)
  {
    sb.Append(child.Element("p").Value);
  }
}

StreamWriter1.WriteLine(link + Environment.NewLine +  Environment.NewLine + sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: yep, doesn't work because all your <p> elements are inside a CDATA node... this needs more work.